# Clojure require namespace: "Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Keyword"

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to split code in 2 files, each with it's own namespace. Following this [tutorial](http://www.xuan-wu.com/pages/2013-09-21-Basic-Web-Application-in-Clojure).

But I get this error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Keyword

I think it's because the namespace being included is not recognised properly.

Main file:

```
(ns mytest2.handler
  (:use compojure.core)
  (:require [compojure.handler :as handler]
            [compojure.route :as route]
            [mytest2.views :as foo] ;<-- line causing error
            [hiccup.core :refer (html)])
  )



(defn layout [title & content]
  (html
   [:head [:title title]]
   [:body content]))

(defn main-page []
  (layout "My Blog"
   [:h1 "My Blog"]
   [:p "Welcome to my page"]))

(defroutes app-routes
  (GET "/" [] (main-page))
  (route/resources "/")
  (route/not-found "Not Found"))

(def app
  (handler/site app-routes))

;    (println (seq (.getURLs (java.lang.ClassLoader/getSystemClassLoader))))
```

Second file:

```
(ns mytest2.views
  :require [hiccup.core :refer (html)]
  )

(defn layout [title & content]
  (html
   [:head [:title title]]
   [:body content]))

(defn main-page []
  (layout "My Blog"
   [:h1 "My Blog"]
   [:p "Welcome to my page"]))
```

(note I copied the functions from mytest2.views in mytest2.handler for testing. They're not supposed to be in mytest2.handler).

Paths of files:

/mytest2/src/mytest2/handler.clj

/mytest2/src/mytest2/views.clj

(where first mytest2 is the name of the project, and the second is part of the path- automatically created by lein).

As you see in the first file I printed the class path to verify that /mytest2/src/mytest2/ is included, and yes it is.

Comment: In addition to @n2o's answer below, shouldn't the referred symbol html be in [ ], not () ? Like `[hiccup.core :refer [html]]`

Comment: @georgek both forms are equal for the compiler, but `[]` is a conventional one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You missed some brackets in your original code

```
;; wrong
(ns mytest2.views
  :require [hiccup.core :refer [html]])
```

There is just one pair of brackets missing. Do it as in your Main file:

```
;; Done right!
(ns mytest2.views
  (:require [hiccup.core :refer [html]]))
```

I am not familar with Compojure so I do not know what you have to require. But you need to add the bracket around `:require`.

Answer (score 26):

Received the same error from trying to use `:refer :all` in Clojurescript, which apparently is against the rules.

Comment: This was the problem I had, not the missing brackets.

Comment: After half an hour trying to debug that, your username sums up my feelings completely